# Move group by aligning its child object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, alignment

I guess this was asked earlier here [Align (Center) based on only one item of a multi-item group?](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/forum.inkscapecomunity.com/indexcd0f.html?topic=1408.0) - but I couldn't really see a solution; so I'll try again:

Consider this situation - the reddish objects are part of a group:

[image: inkscape-objects]

I would like to align the selected red rectangle (the child in the group) left with the grey rectangle - *and* move the enclosing group correspondingly.

Of course, in the above situation, I can do Ctrl+Shift+LeftClick of the gray rectangle, and click on Left Align - but that will just move the red rectangle child, and will leave the other group members in place.

Any way to do this easily in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that with the align tools.

A workaround is to use snapping.  Objects within a group will still snap.
Enable *Snap to Cusp Nodes*, or if you want to align centre, there's a *Snap Midpoints* option in the Snap controls bar. Then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag to constrain the position.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks - went with this answer because it's explicit about "no way to do that with the align tools", and "Objects within a group will still snap"

Answer (score 1):

Drag a vertical guide from the ruler to the left edge of the grey shape. It should snap if you have the point snappings on:

[image]

Select the group. Hold Ctrl to limit the motion to horizontal. Move the group until the pink rectangle snaps to the guide:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - using a ruler/guide in this context is a great tip.